# Authentication: AppPool is set to NETWORK SERVICE user, but DB is getting DOMAIN\MACHINE$ user?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, iis-6

This is vexing and searching around it is producing a lot of useless results (returning problems about NETWORK SERVICE not authenticating - oh to have that particular problem!).

I have deployed an ASP.NET MVC 2 application to an IIS6 and 7 webserver, with the Application Pool set to authenticate as NETWORK SERVICE. However, I get the SQL error:

Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\SERVERNANE$'.

So why is it using this user and not NETWORK SERVICE? To frig it I tried to add a new login for the user, but obviously, it doesn't work.

My web.config if you need it for  settings ...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="ApplicationServices"
            connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=<redacted>CrewChangeover.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

      <add name="<redacted>.CrewChangeoverConnectionString"
 connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=<redacted>CrewChangeover.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      <add name="<redacted>_HR_FullConnectionString"
 connectionString="Data Source=<redacted>\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=<redacted>;Integrated Security=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network Service *is* that user!

Network Service impersonates the computer account when trying to connect to an off-box resource. Granting permissions to DOMAIN\Servername$ *does* generally work, though.

So, the rough breakdown is:

- Local Service - low-privileged, connects to external resources as NULL
- Network Service - low-privileged, connects to external resources as DOMAIN\Computer$
- LocalSystem - high-privileged, connects to external resources as DOMAIN\Computer$

If you want the App Pool to authenticate as a specific Windows user:

- Don't use impersonation (it doesn't look like you are)
- Run the App Pool as that specific Windows user

And Robert should be your mother's brother.

Comment: Thanks Tristan. What seems to have happened is your answer made it clear how it "suddenly" stopped working, was deploying to one location with the sol config of another (idiot!). Which highlighted the user difference. Thanks very much, educational.